# Vector of vectors is not copied correctly (C++)

Tags: c++, vector, graph

I am trying to write a class for directed graphs with very simple functionality like adding and removing edges. For some reason the default-copy constructor does not do its job and I wonder why.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Graph.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Graph g1(1);
    g1.insertEdge(0, 0);
    Graph g2(g1);

    cout << (g1 == g2) << endl; // false
    return 0;
}
```

Graph.h:

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H_INCLUDE
#define GRAPH_H_INCLUDE

#include <vector>

class Graph
{
public:
    typedef unsigned int vertex_t;
    typedef std::vector< std::vector<bool> > edges_set_t;

    vertex_t vertices;
    edges_set_t edges;

    Graph(vertex_t vertices = 0)
        : vertices(vertices)
    {
        initEdges();
    }

    void insertEdge(vertex_t v, vertex_t w)
    {
        edges[v][w] = 1;
    }

    bool hasEdge(vertex_t v, vertex_t w) const
    {
        return edges[v][w];
    }


private:
    void initEdges()
    {
        edges = std::vector< std::vector<bool> >(vertices);
        while (edges.size() < vertices)
            edges.push_back(std::vector<bool>(vertices));
    }
};



bool operator==(const Graph& g, const Graph& h)
{
    if (g.vertices != h.vertices)
        return false;

    for (Graph::vertex_t v = 0; v < g.vertices; ++v)
        for (Graph::vertex_t w = 0; w < g.vertices; ++w)
            if ((g.hasEdge(v, w) && !h.hasEdge(v, w)) || (!g.hasEdge(v, w) && h.hasEdge(v, w)))
                return false;

    return true;
}





#endif
```

In my main function, I create a graph with a single vertex and add a self-loop onto it. I then try to copy it using the default copy constructor, which somehow gives me a graph with the correct number of vertices but no edges at all.

The same is true if I use this constructor:

```
Graph(const Graph& other)
{
    vertices = other.vertices;
    initEdges();
    edges = other.edges;
}
```

However, it works correctly with this, for some reason I cannot find:

```
Graph(const Graph& other)
{
    vertices = other.vertices;
    initEdges();
    for (Graph::vertex_t v = 0; v < vertices; ++v) // no idea why a manual implementation is necessary
        for (Graph::vertex_t w = 0; w < vertices; ++w)
            if (other.hasEdge(v, w))
                insertEdge(v, w);
}
```

Comment: `initEdges` doesn't do what you think it does - it creates a vector of *empty* vectors.

Comment: `edges = std::vector< std::vector<bool> >(vertices);` implies `edges.size() == vertices` afterwards. Did you mean to call `reserve` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop

```
while (edges.size() < vertices)
```

never gets entered, because the constructor you call adds empty vectors for each element of the vector. To make sure that you get a square matrix, use

```
edges = std::vector< std::vector<bool> >(vertices, std::vector<bool>(vertices));
```

This can be moved into member intialization list of `Graph`, rendering `initEdges()` unnecessary.

Moreover, you can drop `vertices` variable, because it is always equal to `edges.size()`.

Your comparison operator does this:

```
if ((g.hasEdge(v, w) && !h.hasEdge(v, w)) || (!g.hasEdge(v, w) && h.hasEdge(v, w)))
```

The condition is equivalent to

```
if (g.hasEdge(v, w) != h.hasEdge(v, w))
```

Since `std::vector` provides `operator ==` which compares the size, you can rewrite your comparison operator as follows:

```
bool operator==(const Graph& g, const Graph& h) {
    return g.edges == h.edges;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/BqDKB7)

Comment: Thank you, for both the answer to my problem and the other suggestions.